# Inequality $\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c \leq \frac{a^8+b^8+c^8}{a^3b^3c^3}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive reals .
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle \frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c \leq \frac{a^8+b^8+c^8}{a^3b^3c^3}$

I found this one in a book, no hints mentioned, but marked as very hard.

I can't make any progress...

Comment: Did you get this problem from a book discussing algebraic inequalities?

Comment: @user74973 No, in a book about real analysis.

Comment: What is the title of the real analysis book?  Do you think that author intended an argument using the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We might make repeated use of the inequality $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge xy+yz+zx$, for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ as well.

We have infact: $$\displaystyle a^8+b^8+c^8 \ge \sum\limits_{cyc} a^4b^4 \ge \sum\limits_{cyc} a^2b^4c^2 \ge \sum\limits_{cyc} ab^2c.bc^2a = \sum\limits_{cyc} a^2b^3c^3 = a^3b^3c^3\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$$

Answer (score 11):

Hint: Use AM-GM inequality we have
$$3a^8+3b^8+2c^8\ge 8a^3b^3c^2$$
proof: since
$$3a^8+3b^8+2c^8=a^8+a^8+a^8+b^8+b^8+b^8+c^8+c^8\ge 8(a^{8+8+8}b^{8+8+8}c^{8+8})^{1/8}=8a^3b^3c^2$$
similar 
$$3a^8+2b^8+3c^8\ge 8a^3b^2c^3$$
$$2a^8+3b^3+3c^3\ge 8a^2b^3c^3$$
so
$$8(a^8+b^8+c^8)\ge 8a^2b^2c^2(ab+bc+ac)$$
so
$$\dfrac{a^8+b^8+c^8}{a^3b^3c^3}\ge\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}$$

Comment: I agree it works, but it's quite out of the blue...